# I am one word. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle

Given the following word, can you try cracking the code shown in the quoted block?

> **ASCII**

Code

> 073 032 097 109 032 097 110 032 101 105 103 104 116 032 108 101 116
>   116 101 114 032 119 111 114 100 046 032
>
> 077 121 032 102 105 114 115 116 032 102 111 117 114 032 108 101 116
>   116 101 114 115 032 099 111 109 098 105 110 101 032 116 111 032 102
>   111 114 109 032 097 110 032 097 116 109 111 115 112 104 101 114 105
>   099 032 115 116 097 116 101 046 032
>
> 077 121 032 116 104 105 114 100 044 032 102 111 117 114 116 104 044
>   032 102 105 102 116 104 044 032 115 105 120 116 104 032 097 110 100
>   032 115 101 118 101 110 116 104 032 108 101 116 116 101 114 115 032
>   103 105 118 101 032 115 117 112 112 111 114 116 046 032
>
> 077 121 032 108 097 115 116 032 116 104 114 101 101 032 108 101 116
>   116 101 114 115 032 105 115 032 116 104 101 032 110 097 109 101 032
>   111 102 032 097 032 112 101 114 115 111 110 046 032 087 104 111 032
>   097 109 032 073 063

Comment: Instead of simply putting ASCII text, you could have added something which is hinting towards decoding it. Welcome to Puzzling. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting ASCII to Text gives -

> I am an eight letter word.
>  My first four letters combine to form an atmospheric state.
>  My third, fourth, fifth, sixth and seventh letters give support.
>  My last three letters is the name of a person. Who am I?

This looks like

> **MISTAKEN** .

Explanation

> **MIST** is an atmospheric state. 
>  **STAKE** can be used as a support. 
> **KEN** is a name of a person.